# <1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1003 [12:8])

Tags: swift, xcode

I am using Xcode Version 9.4.1 simulater, I am getting this error:

```
<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1003 [12:8])
2018-08-15 05:14:42.275912+0000 FoodTaskerMobile[10864:360131] Task <04D22041-2589-440F-AB57-2E4C2FFFF4CF>.<1> finished with error - code: -1003



  // API to login an user
    func login(userType: String, completionHandler: @escaping (NSError?) -> Void) {

        let path = "api/social/convert-token/"
        let url = baseURL!.appendingPathComponent(path)
        let params: [String: Any] = [
            "grant_type": "convert_token",
            "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
            "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET,
            "backend": "facebook",
            "token": FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString,
            "user_type": userType
        ]
```

and

```
import Foundation

let BASE_URL: String = "http://loaclhost:8000"
let CLIENT_ID: String = "gvJawJBuORje858lQS4HBzTBHC84vUuzzw5vzjNi"
let CLIENT_SECRET: String = "vkqJhkDbc3UOsxpxrlaXMwuReGVrWs9T55TmDixpFTGBTlY0MAtS9WsggM5Zaojnjw8LnfxB5k7fhKUfakhmsEmQgyKKZMsnckcUY4quCCsU3PH0qwRZoraQNjiE30Nf"
```

I have tried this way but still not fixe.

[image]

Comment: code: -1003 means **CannotFindHost**. Is your url (especially the host part) valid?

Comment: this is the url
let BASE_URL: String = "http://loaclhost:8000"

Comment: Usually, iOS simulator can connect to the server running on the host mac with localhost. Are you sure the server is running and waiting input on port 8000? if the problem was caused by ATS settings, you would get another code. It is hard to say any more, as you are hiding your code and how you set up your local server on your mac.

Comment: // API to login an user
    func login(userType: String, completionHandler: @escaping (NSError?) -> Void) {
    
        let path = "api/social/convert-token/"
        let url = baseURL!.appendingPathComponent(path)
        let params: [String: Any] = [
            "grant_type": "convert_token",
            "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
            "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET,
            "backend": "facebook",
            "token": FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString,
            "user_type": userType
        ]

Comment: You can _edit_ your own question and include those codes into your question. But as far as I can see, there's no clue you get code: -1003 unless your server is not running.

Comment: Did you maybe just mistype "localhost" in your `BASE_URL`("http://`loaclhost`:8000")?